# To read the source of a given url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010

I have a website url. my task is too read the source of whole page into a variable.
I am trying this as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    debugger;
    $(documnet).ready(function () {
        var timer =
            $.ajax({ type: 'post', url: 'http://WWW.google.com', data: { content: src } });
        });


    alert(timer);
</script>
```

Currently this is not working it is not extracting the source.Please assist if there is any bug or if there is any other solution to complete this task.

Answer (score 4):

Using the .ajax method you can't really read data from arbitrary sites. When running JavaScript in a browser you have the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) which basically says you can only read data from the same server which the page is hosted on. There are ways around using CORS, or JSONP. CORS requires that the server you are pulling data front grand you permission (which isn't going to happen for google). JSONP also needs configuration on the server and is meant for data that is returned via json and not as a webpage.

Really the only reliable way to do this is to have a server side page on your site do the http request. You use .ajax to call an endpoint on your server, fetch the webpage server side and return it via the ajax call.

Edit: based on the comment below you want to load pages on the same server. I looked at your ajax code and it needs to be adjusted

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(documnet).ready(function () {
    var request = $.ajax({ type: 'GET', url: 'file.html' });

    request.done(function(response){
           //response now has the webpage
         });
    });


</script>
```

Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/4h4l1dwPpQyYsOvJTfO1?p=preview

Comment: the websiite are hosted on the local server. so the problem of authentication wont come. But the issue remains the same how shall i fetch the complete source to a variable.

Comment: if it's on the same site you just need to use the ajax call normally. I updated my answer above to include a working code sampe.